# PHP mkdir in lnk, is it possible

Tags: php, directory, shortcut, mkdir

Strange question, I have a "lnk" folder (Windows shortcut), php can find it and see it using:

```
<?php
$dir    = '/uploads/test';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$files2 = scandir($dir, 1);

print_r($files1);
print_r($files2);
?>
```

This works well and shows the lnk file "test.lnk"

I'm trying to create an upload folder inside the test.lnk shortcut using the code to check if its there, if not create it..

```
if (!is_dir($dirname)) {
    mkdir($dirname);
}
```

I have gone over the PHP manual and google and I cannot find an answer, I've tried the is_link as well.

Can this be done at all ?

Comment: So which part of this is not working, the checking whether the desired folder already exists, or the creation of it?

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for replying - I cannot create a folder inside the lnk . PHP says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you tried using `realpath` to get the shortcut resolved, and then check existence of the folder & attempt its creation via that? (It works with symlinks according to docs, not sure if the same is true for these Windows shortcuts.)

Comment: Thankyou CBroe, it does see the whole path and returns it (using echo). It has to be a permissions issue then ?

Comment: If it was, you should be getting a warning from mkdir then. Did you try to use the full path now? What does `is_writable` say?

Comment: Well, I have gone a different way as time was short (as in needed by tomorrow!) It isnt the solution I wanted/needed nor the cleanest. Your suggestions and help have been brilliant, thank you CBroe.